# Composite C1 - Change design / layout of Blog

Tags: c1-cms

I have added a blog to my Composite C1 website - using the standard blog module.

It works fine - but I can find no way to change the layout / edit its HTML - is this possible? Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello myself 3 years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can change the styles used in the blog.

The blog's stylesheet can be found here: ~\Frontend\Composite\Community\Blog\Styles.css

Then, you can also edit the Razor functions that emit the blog's markup:

Functions / Razor Functions / Composite / Community / Blog

The function that shows the blog posts as a list as well as an individual post is called "BlogRenderer".